# How to use the Python getpass.getpass in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm

I have found getpass does not work in PyCharm.  It just hangs.

In fact is seems msvcrt.getch and raw_input also don't work, so perhaps the issue is not with getpass. Instead with the 'i' bit of PyCharm's stdio handling.

The problem is, I can't put my personal password into code as it would end up in SVN which would be visible to other people.  So I use getpass to get my password each time.

On searching, all I can find is that "Pycharm does dome hacking to get Django working with getpass" but no hint as to what that hack is....

I've looked at getpass and it uses msvcrt on Windows (so this problem might only be on Windows)

My question is: Is there a workround for this issue?

Comment: Same problem in Ubuntu 18 and 22 on Linux environment.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

## For PyCharm 2018.3

Go to 'Edit Configurations' and then select 'Emulate terminal in output console'.

[image]

Comment: Run >> Edit Configurations... , but this only works for Run, not for Debug.

Comment: @James It works for me on Windows 10 in Debug mode too.

Comment: This works, but if you request two passwords one after the other, it skips the second one.

Comment: Worked in debug for me both with and without checking this option. Only difference is without it checked, it actually showed the password I typed.

BTW, I was using Intellij with Python plugin.

Comment: Thanks a lot it works, finally I can run and debug getpass fn

Comment: I can't seem to be able to type into getpass though after doing this. However, when I do run with python console it works fine

Comment: Should note I think this option has moved again

Answer (score 7):

I've run into this running Pycharm CE 4.5 on Windows.  The workaround I use is to run your program in debug mode, then you get a console tab where you can enter your password when using getpass.

Answer (score 2):

A common solution to this would be to store the credentials in a file which you mark ignored by your VCS. Then just:

```
with open('credentials.txt') as f:
    user, pw = f.read().split('\n')  # or similar
```

Alternatively, have them specified in environment variables. Both of these methods should work around PyCharm's handling of `stdin`.

Comment: Store your password in a file?

Answer (score 2):

At first use, my code in pycharm and then click the "Run" then click the "Edit Configurations" then select the 'Emulate terminal in output console'

```
from selenium import webdriver
from getpass import getpass
email=input("Enter the email:")
password= getpass("Enter the password:")
driver=webdriver.Chrome()
url='https://www.facebook.com/'
driver.get(url)
user_id=driver.find_element_by_id("email")
user_id.send_keys(email)
user_password=driver.find_element_by_id("pass")
user_password.send_keys(password)
login_button = 
driver.find_element_by_id("u_0_b").click()
time.sleep(30)
```

Comment: At first use, my code in pycharm and then click the "Run" then click the "Edit Configurations" then select the 'Emulate terminal in output console'

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, getpass() tends to fail miserably (I tested it with IDLE and PyScripter without any success on Python 3.4). I would suggest using passwordbox from easygui - it works wonderfully provided you do not use ver. 0.98 (something is messed up there), it is safe to use ver. 0.96.

Download easygui ver. 0.96, unpack it to a temporary folder, and from that folder install it with:

```
python setup.py install
```

and use passwordbox in your program:

```
from easygui import passwordbox
password = passwordbox("PASSWORD:")
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, even after setting the configuration to "**Emulate terminal in output console**" getpass.getpass() didn't work. To solve the problem, "**I set the configuration to Run With Python Console**"
[Editing the configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kn4P7.png)

But there was a different problem now: The console was echoing the password in the python console. If you don't want that to happen, I recommend you to run the program using cmd or Linux terminal. The output in Linux terminal looked like this:
[Output in Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BsViE.png)