# Is there a way to asterisk an input as it's being typed?

Tags: python

I've to make this code where I have to take a customers order and then take a form of payment. For the card payment I was wondering if there was a way to have the input replaced with asterisks as they were typed. There is a line where I ask them to input their pin which is as follows:

```
pin=input("Insert your pin") #Asks user for pin number.
```

Let's say the pin is 1234. Instead of it showing 1234 as it is typed, is there a way to make it go `****` when it's being typed. I've tried using `.getpass();` whether or not I've used it right I don't know. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can't be totally sure, but isn't this a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/27631629/3934789 ?

Comment: You said you've tried `getpass`. What's wrong with that?

Comment: Please show us what you have tried.

Comment: With regards to getpass, I imported it at the start of the code and tried to put it at the end of the input line.

Comment: Show real code. We cannot guess *exactly* what you have done without it. Hell lies in the detail...

Comment: paymentType=input("Card or Cash? ").lower() #Asks the user how they'd like to pay.
        if paymentType == "card": #Recognises the user said card.
            print("Insert card into reader and follow on-screen instructions") #Telling the customer what they've to do.
            time.sleep(4) #Wait 4 seconds for effect.
            pin=input("Insert your pin") #Asks user for pin number.
            time.sleep(2) #Waits 2 seconds for effect.
            print("Thank you! Have a nice day") #End of the sale.
            break #End of the program.

Comment: That's what I use for the card input

Comment: @MarshallShaw So you haven't tried `getpass` ... ?

Answer (score 0):

Getpass would usually just be used like:

```
from getpass import getpass

pin = getpass()
```

Worth noting in some IDEs can cause problems. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28579468/how-to-use-the-python-getpass-getpass-in-pycharm) for example.