# asking for username and password from user using python

Tags: python

I am trying to write a code to fetch data from VM using python.

To start I am trying to ask username and password (not visible or display special character) just how we do in powershell using  **Get-Credential**

I tried below code, it is asking for username but password prompt us not coming

```
import winrm, getpass
try:
    usrname = input("Enter Username: ")
    passwd = input("Enter Password: ", getpass.getpass())
except Exception as err:
   print('Error Occured : ', err)
```

Can you please let me know what is wrong. I am using Pycharm to write and execute my code in windows.

Comment: `getpass.getpass` handles input itself. It doesn't need to be passed to `input` function. Just use `passwd = getpass.getpass('Enter Password: ')`

Comment: @ЕвгенийКрамаров: tried this. but still it is not prompting for password. after entering username when i hit enter, it is blank.

Comment: Have you tried referring to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28579468/how-to-use-the-python-getpass-getpass-in-pycharm)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use the Python getpass.getpass in PyCharm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28579468/how-to-use-the-python-getpass-getpass-in-pycharm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input function in Python only takes one argument. To get the password, you can do this :

```py
try:
    usrname = input("Enter Username: ")
    passwd = getpass.getpass("Enter your password: ")
except Exception as err:
   print('Error Occured : ', err)
```

Comment: tried this. but still it is not prompting for password. after entering username when i hit enter, it is blank.

Comment: Can you put some other part of the code ? Such as the way around calling the prompt, if it's a function or something ? Did you try adding breakpoints on PyCharm to see what's happening while runtime ?