I can't get my password masked using Python trying getpass, getpass4, pwinput or maskpass in Pycharm
I have tried a number of packages in an attempt to input my password but have it masked but none of these worked for me in Pycharm. I ran the same code in Jupyter and it worked. I wonder if this is a known issue and if there is a workaround?
When I try using getpass it just gets stuck. I start the program an no prompt comes up. When I input something in the terminal nothing happens.
from getpass import getpass

pwd=getpass('Please enter password: ')

When I try the other methods, maskpass for example, the default prompt does come up but as I type my password, it doesn't get masked.
import maskpass

pwd=askpass()


The ability for getpass to suppress the input as you're typing actually depends on the terminal that is executing the python code. For PyCharm in particular see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28579468/how-to-use-the-python-getpass-getpass-in-pycharm
